# How to "send" form data to a C# code, then have C# "send" data back?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

This is the HTML form I have, I want to send the user's selection to an aspx.cs file that will process their selection and output something onto the lower textbox.

```html
<!-- Form -->
<form action="lGen.aspx" method="post" id="lForm" runat="server">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <select id="list" form="lForm">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="1" class="validate" >Option 1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input placeholder="Instert Text" id="insText" type="text" class="validate" runat="server" />
      <label for="system_id"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      Checkbox
      <p class="black-text">
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="check1" />
      <label for="check1"><span class="black-text">Check 1</span></label>
      </p>
      <p class="black-text">
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="check2" />
      <label for="check2"><span class="black-text">Check 2</span></label>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      Radio
      <p>
      <input class="with-gap" name="licenseType" type="radio" id="radio1" />
      <label for="radio1"><span class="black-text">Permanent</span></label>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <br />
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light black" onclick="generate_onclick()">
    Generate
    </button>
  </div>
</form>

<!-- TEXT AREA-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <textarea id="genText" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
    <label for="genText"><span class="black-text">Generated</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The aspx.cs I have is this:

```
namespace lGenerator
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string list{ get;  set; }
        public bool check1{ get;  set; }
        public bool check2{ get;  set; }
        public bool radio1{ get;  set; }
        public string genText { get;  set; }

        // Generate License on Click button
        private void generate_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            genL();
        }

        // Creating actual license
        private void genL()
        {
            string phrase = list; 

            licenseText = phrase;
        }
    }
}
```

Just for testing, I wanted to pass the value of whatever they selected on the list and then show it on the textbox below. I'm aware that in PHP, you can use things like $_POST to get values from post but how do I do it with HTML and C#?

Note that I had to change some of the values/IDs and I need to get it working with C# because I will be working with .dlls in the future.

Comment: Recommended this be closed as too broad.  This is WebForms 101, and the concept of a "PostBack" is integral to web forms development.  I recommend following one of the numerous "getting started" guides available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make those controls as server side control by including the property `Runat="server"` and then you can access those control instance values anywhere in your code behind (I mean `*.cs` file).

Comment: By controller you mean like <input type="checkbox" ...  Runat="server" /> ?